# How to Cast geometry to Geography in SQL script in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-spatial, geography-data-type, typecast

I have a Table with some spatial Data in MS SQL Server. The datatype of the spatial column is `geometry`.

I'm trying to get the closest data from an input file using the following query:

```
DECLARE @g geometry;  
SET @g= geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-74.19432 43.745)', 4326); 

SELECT TOP(1) Shape,  Shape.ToString(), UID, Colour, Shape.STDistance(@g) FROM dbo.roads  
WHERE Shape.STDistance(@g) IS NOT NULL  
ORDER BY Shape.STDistance(@g);
```

This query runs successfully, but I want the distance between my input point and the Shape in meters; Right now the value is in Decimal Degrees, since my data is WGS84-lat-long.

To get Distance in Meters, I need to convert the `geometry` on the fly to `Geography`

I can't find the syntax to do this Casting in the Select Clause of the Query.

(All the [examples](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78afd2b7-f7b6-4327-be7c-a8a365e703a2/i-need-to-find-distance-between-2-address-in-a-table-in-my-database?forum=transactsql) [That I find](http://blogs.msdn.com/edkatibah/archive/2008/08/19/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-1b.aspx), do the casting outside the Actual Select statement. )

How do I temporarily cast the geometry to geography on the fly?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way of doing it, but it certainly works:

```
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText([geom].STAsText(),4326)
```

where 4326 is the spatial reference ID (SRID)

Comment: This was really helpful for my [issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413831/sql-server-stintersects-stdistance-and-stcointains-with-lat-lon-points-and-geom)!
Thanks! ;-)