# SQL Server STIntersects, STDistance and STCointains with Lat Lon points and Geometry Polygons

Tags: distance, intersection, sql-server, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

I need to create 3 functions in SQL Server (2017) that has to do the following:

- `IsPointInsideTown(Point, TownCode, [SRID]) -> true/false`: indicates if the point is inside the town's polygon.
- `TownOfPoint(Point, [SRID]) -> TownCode`: indicates which is the town's polygon that contains the point.
- `DistanceFromTown(Point, TownCode, [SRID]) -> meters`: calculate the minimal distance from the point and the specified town's polygon.

I've created the `TownBoundaries` table (layer) with a `GEOMETRY` data type column with `EPSG:4326 WGS 84` SRID, using QGIS v3.20.

This is the QGIS Information window about the *original* source Shapefile of the boundaries.

[image: Shapefile layer info]

and this is the Information window about the final *converted* layer on the SQL Server database.

[image: SQL Server layer info]

The source CRS has been converted from `EPSG:32632 WGS 84 UTM Zone 32N` to `EPSG:4326 WGS 84` to make it compatible with the Lat/Lon coordinates that I need to check using the described functions.

The points to check come from GPS devices and are sent to the system in Latitude/Longitude degrees format (ie: 53.553813, 9.99158).

##### Implementations of the 3 functions

```
-- IsPointInsideTown: WORKS!

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION IsPointInsideTown (
    @Latitude FLOAT,
    @Longitude FLOAT,
    @TownCode CHAR(6),
    @SRID INT = 4326
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value BIT;
    
    SELECT @return_value = Geom.STIntersects(GEOMETRY::Point(@Longitude, @Latitude, @SRID))
    FROM [GeoData].[dbo].[V_Towns] 
    WHERE TownCode = @TownCode

    RETURN @return_value
END;

-- TownOfPoint: WORKS!

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION TownOfPoint (
    @Latitude FLOAT,
    @Longitude FLOAT,
    @SRID INT = 4326
)
RETURNS CHAR(6)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value CHAR(6);
    
    SELECT @return_value = TownCode
    FROM [GeoData].[dbo].[V_Towns]
    WHERE Geom.STContains(GEOMETRY::Point(@Longitude, @Latitude, @SRID)) = 1

    RETURN @return_value
END;

-- DistanceFromTown: NOT WORKING!

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION DistanceFromTown (
    @Latitude FLOAT,
    @Longitude FLOAT,
    @TownCode CHAR(6),
    @SRID INT = 4326
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value FLOAT;
    
    SELECT @return_value = Geom.STDistance(GEOMETRY::Point(@Longitude, @Latitude, @SRID))
    FROM [GeoData].[dbo].[V_Towns]
    WHERE TownCode = @TownCode

    RETURN @return_value
END;
```

The first 2 functions (`IsPointInsideTown` and `TownOfPoint`) are working correctly. I've made some tests and then checked on QGIS map.

`DistanceFromTown` instead, is NOT working properly. It gives me a result that is not the correct measure in meters. It's always a `0,x` number when it's actually thousands of meters.

I found out (see [STDistance Unit in SQL Server 2008](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/stdistance-unit-in-sql-server-2008) and [MS SQL Server's STDistance output differs from Google Earth/Maps straight line distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/ms-sql-servers-stdistance-output-differs-from-google-earth-maps-straight-line-d)) that in order to make the `STDistance` function works correctly with Lat/Lon coordinates, I should use the `GEOGRAPHY` data type and not `GEOMETRY`.

##### Questions

1. As said, from the test I've made it seems that `IsPointInsideTown` and `TownOfPoint` are working properly, **even if they're making "mixed" use** of the `GEOMETRY` data type and Lat/Lon coordinates, but is it really correct or is there another (*better*) way to do that?
2. How can I make the `DistanceFromTown` function works as well? I initially thought about using `STTransform()` to convert Lat/Lon Points to Points with plain coordinates (*also for the other 2 functions*), but I know that unfortunately the function is not implemented on SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

1. [How to Cast geometry to Geography in SQL script in MS SQL Server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283968/how-to-cast-geometry-to-geography-in-sql-script-in-ms-sql-server)
2. [STDistance between point and polygon always returns 0 even though they are miles away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267640/stdistance-between-point-and-polygon-always-returns-0-even-though-they-are-miles)

I found a solution!

As said by @PeterS in his answer (Question 1 above), it's probably not the best solution in terms of performance, but it works!

And thanks to @Ben Thul (Question 2 above) I found a solution to distance = 0 issue when the point is inside the polygon.

This is the updated implementation of my `DistanceFromTown` function.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION DistanceFromTown (
    @Latitude FLOAT,
    @Longitude FLOAT,
    @TownCode CHAR(6),
    @InnerDistance BIT = 0,
    @SRID INT = 4326
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value FLOAT;
    DECLARE @pointAsGeometry GEOMETRY;
    DECLARE @pointAsGeography GEOGRAPHY;

    SET @pointAsGeometry = GEOMETRY::Point(@Longitude, @Latitude, @SRID);
    SET @pointAsGeography = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@Longitude, @Latitude, @SRID);
    
    SELECT @return_value = 
        CASE 
            -- Point outside of Polygon
            WHEN Geom.STIntersects(@pointAsGeometry) = 0 
                THEN GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(Geom.STAsText(), 4326).MakeValid().ReorientObject().STDistance(@pointAsGeography)
            -- Point inside Polygon and inner distance flag FALSE
            WHEN Geom.STIntersects(@pointAsGeometry) = 1 AND @InnerDistance = 0 
                THEN 0
            -- Point inside Polygon (with Envelope angle < 180°) and inner distance flag TRUE
            WHEN Geom.STIntersects(@pointAsGeometry) = 1 AND GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(Geom.STAsText(), 4326).MakeValid().EnvelopeAngle() < 180 AND @InnerDistance = 1 
                THEN GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(Geom.STAsText(), 4326).MakeValid().ReorientObject().STDistance(@pointAsGeography)
            -- Point inside Polygon (with Envelope angle = 180°) and inner distance flag TRUE
            WHEN Geom.STIntersects(@pointAsGeometry) = 1 AND GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(Geom.STAsText(), 4326).MakeValid().EnvelopeAngle() = 180 AND @InnerDistance = 1 
                THEN GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(Geom.STAsText(), 4326).MakeValid().STDistance(@pointAsGeography)
        END
    FROM [GeoData].[dbo].[V_Towns]
    WHERE TownCode = @TownCode

    RETURN @return_value
END;
```

##### Usage

```
DECLARE @Latitude FLOAT = 45.123450
DECLARE @Longitude FLOAT = 10.987650

-- Point outside of Polygon
SELECT [GeoData].[dbo].DistanceFromTown(@Latitude, @Longitude, '00001', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
-- Point inside of Polygon (not considering inner distance)
SELECT [GeoData].[dbo].DistanceFromTown(@Latitude, @Longitude, '00002', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
-- Point inside of Polygon (getting the inner distance)
SELECT [GeoData].[dbo].DistanceFromTown(@Latitude, @Longitude, '00002', 1, DEFAULT)
```